# Updated 12.04 RC to final, does not boot up

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

I updated my 12.04 RC (64-bit) to kernel 3.2.0-24 and now it does not boot the GUI from grub. I can still launch the 3.2.0-20 and the new kernel via recovery mode. When I try to launch it straight from grub, I get just the blank screen.

Comment: Are you trying to launch Lightdm? or are you using other display managers? I have been using lightdm and got some problems

Answer (score 1):

how did you update? I'm not for certain, but you might have to do a fresh install. at least that's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, however after booting back into the old kernel I just installed the proprietary ATI drivers for my video card from within the driver updater and then it booted using the newest kernels. Ive also updated 3.2.0-24 to 3.3.4 and same exact thing, I needed to reload the ATI drivers yet again. Not sure if this is what is happening to you though.

SkOrPn